# How to avoid "ConcurrentModificationException" while add ArrayList elements?

Tags: java, concurrentmodificationexception

I'm trying to add an item to the ArrayList in a certain order

```
Iterator<Rating> it = arr.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Rating o = it.next();
    int index = arr.indexOf(o);
    if(o.getRating() < this.getRating()) {
        arr.add(index, this);
    }
}
```

I get a ConcurrentModificationException when trying to do it. Is there some simple solution to solve this problem?

Comment: If you can get a `listIterator()`, by calling add on the iterator. Otherwise: find the index, add element after iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps one of the following collections will serve in place of the `ArrayList`?

A [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) will let you write without causing a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Whether it is a good choice or not depends on the relative frequency of writes to iterations.

Also, consider the [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) as it will automatically handle ordering, or [PriorityBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) if there are concurrent use considerations.

Comment: But even concurrent data structures shouldn't be modified _from the same iterator_ while you are iterating over them. The result might not be, what you expect.

Comment: @knittl Did you mean *should be modified from the same iterator*? A ConcurrentModificationException happens if a collection is modified outside of the iterator. If you modify through the iterator, it works fine.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry, I have not expressed myself clearly. You shouldn't modify a collection via collection methods. Calling methods on the iterator is OK (as you have pointed out, thanks!). Modifying them from a different thread is OK for concurrent collections. What you shouldn't do is (simplified): `var iterator = coll.iterator(); while (iterator.hasNext()) { coll.remove(iterator.next()); }` (or add, set, etc.) You will not get an exception, but it almost certainly hints at a flaw in your program or a misunderstanding how collections work (besides the obvious O(n²) behavior in my example).